# windows server 2003 language settings change

Tags: windows-server-2003, settings, language, user-settings

So my Windows Server 2003 is entirely in German. For practical reasons, I wanted to change the language for my account to English, however it prooved to be more problematic than I thought.

I think in newer versions of Win Server, not even a reboot is necessary for the changes to take effect. However in 2003 I was convinced it was required.

I changed the language under Language - Advanced (if my translation is correct) to English, which was already available. All the other location settings stayed the same as they were (German). I rebooted the server, hoping to log into a server in English.. but it's still German. 
[Language settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0l9t.jpg)

Am I missing something here ? Could someone (who's done this before) give me instructions on how to change the language (in menus, interfaces, descriptions etc.) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Changes made in described *Language - Advanced* dialogues affect merely *input language*. The input language is a setting in Windows that controls the language you use to type information on your computer (and could link to e.g. spell checker).

To change the *interface language* (for a particular user) to English you'll need the English MUI (Multilingual User Interface). See [Frequently Asked Questions: Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 MUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688178.aspx) for details.

Pay your attention to technical particulars as well as to licensing terms.